# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'cliente' available as request attribute

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I'm facing an issue with spring and thymeleaf, i'm trying to fill a form with data from an entity called cliente, but i'm getting a Whitelabel Error Page message in the browser and this message in the console

```
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'cliente' available as request attribute
```

this is the Cliente

```
package com.bolsadeideasspringboot.app.models.entity;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

@Entity
@Table(name="clientes")
public class Cliente implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NotEmpty
    private String nombre;
    @NotEmpty
    private String apellido;
    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    private String email;
    @Column(name="create_at")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date createAt;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }
    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public Date getCreateAt() {
        return createAt;
    }
    public void setCreateAt(Date createAt) {
        this.createAt = createAt;
    }

}
```

this is the controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/form/{id}")
    public String editar(@ModelAttribute("form") @PathVariable(value="id")Long id, Map<String, Object>model) {
    Cliente cliente = null;

    if(id > 0) {
        clientedao.findOne(id);
        model.put("cliente", cliente);
        model.put("titulo", "Editar Cliente");
        return "form";
    }
    else {
        return "redirect:/listar";
    }

}
```

this is the ClienteDaoImpl.java method

```
@Override
public Cliente findOne(Long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return em.find(Cliente.class, id);
}
```

this is the Dao interface method

```
public Cliente findOne(Long id);
```

and this is the form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title th:text="${titulo}">Insert title here</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-3">
                <h1 class="text-success" th:text="${titulo}"></h1>
                <form th:action="@{/form}" th:object="${cliente}" method="post">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Nombre</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{nombre}" placeholder="Nombre"/>
                        <small class="form-text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('nombre')}" th:errors="*{nombre}"></small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">    
                        <label>Apellido</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{apellido}" placeholder="Apellido"/>
                        <small class="form-text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('apellido')}" th:errors="*{apellido}"></small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">    
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{email}" placeholder="correo@ejemplo.com"/>
                        <small class="form-text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="*{email}"></small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">    
                        <label>Fecha</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{createAt}" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"/>
                        <small class="form-text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('createAt')}" th:errors="*{createAt}"></small>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="form-group">    
                        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Crear Cliente" />
                    </div>

                    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

i'm setting the cliente in the controller method and i'm using th:object in the form, so i don't know what i'm doing wrong, any help would be helpul, thanks in advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `put()`, try using the recommended approach to adding an object to your model with

`model.addAttribute("cliente", clientedao.findOne(id));`

You typically want to use `@GetMapping` as well for your requests to populate the form.  And use `@PostMapping` for submissions.

Aside: also take a look at Project Lombok to make your beans less error-prone and more readable.  You could remove all those getters and setters and just annotate the class with `@Data`.

While not deprecated, you'll also want to move away from using `java.util.Date` and use the newer date/time classes.

Comment: thank bro, but i already solved this issue, the thing is, i didn't assigne the value of (clientedao.findOne(id)) to the clientes variable, but i'll give you the accepted answer (i don't know how to close the topic xd)

Comment: You are correct!  I will update the answer for future readers anyway